# Configuring database username and password in Compound JS project (MongoDB)

Tags: node.js

I have started using CompoundJS with MongoDB as database.
I know i should do the host configuration in `/config/database.json`,
but not sure how i should add username/password for database configuration.

I tried to add username/password like below, but its not functional

```
{ "development":
  { "driver":   "mongoose"
  , "url": "mongodb://localhost/stats_development",
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "123456"
  }
, "test":
  { "driver":   "mongoose"
  , "url": "mongodb://localhost/stats_test",
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "123456"
  }
, "production":
  { "driver":   "mongoose"
  , "url": "mongodb://localhost/stats_production",
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "123456"
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "it's not functional" ?

Comment: after i do this configuration it shows like unauthorized database..
i have checked the valid username/password pair to authenticate db.. but its correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution..

`mongodb://user:password@host:port/dbname`

Thanks to Sagish, Reference : https://github.com/1602/compound/issues/377